How can I transform this SVG code to not use <defs> but still achieve the same result?
I have a SVG that I need to make work in godot engine. Godot doesn't see any SVGs that contain "defs" or other complicated stuff.
My question is how can I change this SVG code to remove < defs > but still achieve the same result?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg height="108.9px" width="108.9px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 54.45, 54.45)">
    <use id="subIndicatorMC" transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -38.55, -38.55)" width="77.15" href="#sprite0"/>
  </g>
  <defs>
    <g id="sprite0" transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 38.6, 38.55)">
      <use height="61.4" id="colorMC1" transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -30.05, -30.7)" width="60.05" href="#sprite1"/>
      <use height="77.15" id="colorMC0" transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -38.6, -38.55)" width="77.15" href="#sprite3"/>
    </g>
    <g id="sprite1" transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 30.05, 30.7)">
      <use height="54.65" transform="matrix(0.379, 0.379, -0.379, 0.379, -9.3404, -29.7338)" width="16.35" href="#sprite2"/>
      <use height="54.65" transform="matrix(-0.379, 0.379, -0.379, -0.379, 29.0338, -9.9904)" width="16.35" href="#sprite2"/>
      <use height="54.65" transform="matrix(-0.379, -0.379, 0.379, -0.379, 9.2904, 29.7338)" width="16.35" href="#sprite2"/>
      <use height="54.65" transform="matrix(0.379, -0.379, 0.379, 0.379, -29.0338, 9.9904)" width="16.35" href="#sprite2"/>
    </g>
    <g id="sprite2" transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 9.4, 26.05)">
      <use height="54.65" transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -9.4, -26.05)" width="16.35" href="#shape0"/>
    </g>
    <g id="shape0" transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 9.4, 26.05)">
      <path d="M-0.05 -19.3 L-0.8 -19.6 Q-1.85 -20.2 -2.15 -21.35 -2.5 -22.55 -1.85 -23.55 -1.3 -24.6 -0.1 -24.9 L2.1 -24.65 Q3.15 -24.05 3.45 -22.85 L3.55 -21.85 4.8 -21.5 Q5.65 -21.05 5.9 -20.1 6.1 -19.2 5.65 -18.35 5.15 -17.5 4.25 -17.25 3.3 -17.0 2.45 -17.5 L2.5 -19.85 2.45 -17.5 1.65 19.65 Q2.65 19.6 3.65 20.15 5.0 20.95 5.45 22.6 5.9 24.15 5.1 25.6 4.25 27.0 2.65 27.45 1.05 27.85 -0.35 27.05 -1.8 26.2 -2.2 24.65 L-2.35 24.05 -2.45 24.05 Q-4.35 24.55 -6.0 23.6 -7.7 22.6 -8.2 20.75 -8.75 18.85 -7.7 17.2 -6.8 15.5 -4.9 15.0 L-2.55 14.95 -1.3 15.45 Q0.35 16.4 0.85 18.3 L1.05 19.7 Q1.0 20.8 0.45 21.9 L-0.2 22.7 0.45 21.9 Q1.0 20.8 1.05 19.7 L0.85 18.3 Q0.35 16.4 -1.3 15.45 L-2.55 14.95 -0.05 -19.3 0.0 -20.6 -0.05 -19.3 M3.25 -20.8 L3.55 -21.85 3.25 -20.8" fill="#666666" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none"/>
      <path d="M3.55 -21.85 L3.45 -22.85 Q3.15 -24.05 2.1 -24.65 L-0.1 -24.9 Q-1.3 -24.6 -1.85 -23.55 -2.5 -22.55 -2.15 -21.35 -1.85 -20.2 -0.8 -19.6 L-0.05 -19.3 0.0 -20.6 M2.45 -17.5 Q3.3 -17.0 4.25 -17.25 5.15 -17.5 5.65 -18.35 6.1 -19.2 5.9 -20.1 5.65 -21.05 4.8 -21.5 L3.55 -21.85 3.25 -20.8 M2.45 -17.5 L2.5 -19.85 M-2.55 14.95 L-1.3 15.45 Q0.35 16.4 0.85 18.3 L1.05 19.7 Q1.0 20.8 0.45 21.9 L-0.2 22.7 M-2.55 14.95 L-4.9 15.0 Q-6.8 15.5 -7.7 17.2 -8.75 18.85 -8.2 20.75 -7.7 22.6 -6.0 23.6 -4.35 24.55 -2.45 24.05 L-2.35 24.05 -2.2 24.65 Q-1.8 26.2 -0.35 27.05 1.05 27.85 2.65 27.45 4.25 27.0 5.1 25.6 5.9 24.15 5.45 22.6 5.0 20.95 3.65 20.15 2.65 19.6 1.65 19.65 L2.45 -17.5 M-0.05 -19.3 L-2.55 14.95" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2.0"/>
    </g>
    <g id="sprite3" transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 38.55, 38.55)">
      <use height="51.05" transform="matrix(0.0, -0.528, 0.5284, 0.0, -38.5637, 8.4216)" width="31.95" href="#sprite4"/>
      <use height="51.05" transform="matrix(0.0, 0.528, -0.5273, 0.0, 38.5843, -8.4216)" width="31.95" href="#sprite4"/>
      <use height="51.05" transform="matrix(0.528, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5284, -8.4216, -38.5637)" width="31.95" href="#sprite4"/>
      <use height="51.05" transform="matrix(-0.528, 0.0, 0.0, -0.5273, 8.4216, 38.5843)" width="31.95" href="#sprite4"/>
    </g>
    <g id="sprite4" transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 15.95, 28.7)">
      <use height="51.05" transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -15.95, -28.7)" width="31.95" href="#shape1"/>
    </g>
    <g id="shape1" transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 15.95, 28.7)">
      <path d="M9.4 -2.4 Q11.3 -6.1 10.2 -9.55 6.05 -10.25 3.75 -7.25 2.35 -5.45 1.0 -6.25 1.95 0.05 9.4 -2.4 M13.6 -20.6 Q16.25 -15.0 13.8 -3.45 15.15 -1.05 11.65 2.4 L10.85 13.9 2.7 20.85 0.0 21.35 -2.65 20.85 -10.85 13.9 -11.6 2.4 Q-15.15 -1.05 -13.75 -3.45 -16.25 -15.0 -13.6 -20.6 -10.35 -27.45 0.0 -27.7 10.35 -27.45 13.6 -20.6 M7.95 11.5 L8.95 6.35 Q7.7 5.65 6.15 6.85 4.75 6.15 3.4 7.2 L-2.7 7.25 Q-3.9 6.0 -5.7 6.9 -7.05 5.45 -8.75 6.35 L-7.8 11.5 Q-6.55 13.65 -5.4 13.5 -3.95 15.05 -2.7 14.65 -1.4 15.8 -0.6 15.4 L0.25 15.0 3.3 14.5 Q4.85 15.25 6.05 13.2 7.15 13.35 7.95 11.5 M-10.1 -9.55 Q-11.25 -6.1 -9.35 -2.4 -1.9 0.05 -1.25 -6.45 -2.25 -5.45 -3.65 -7.25 -5.95 -10.25 -10.1 -9.55" fill="#cccccc" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none"/>
      <path d="M13.6 -20.6 Q10.35 -27.45 0.0 -27.7 -10.35 -27.45 -13.6 -20.6 -16.25 -15.0 -13.75 -3.45 -15.15 -1.05 -11.6 2.4 L-10.85 13.9 -2.65 20.85 0.0 21.35 2.7 20.85 10.85 13.9 11.65 2.4 Q15.15 -1.05 13.8 -3.45 16.25 -15.0 13.6 -20.6" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2.0"/>
      <path d="M9.4 -2.4 Q11.3 -6.1 10.2 -9.55 6.05 -10.25 3.75 -7.25 2.35 -5.45 1.0 -6.25 1.95 0.05 9.4 -2.4 M-10.1 -9.55 Q-11.25 -6.1 -9.35 -2.4 -1.9 0.05 -1.25 -6.45 -2.25 -5.45 -3.65 -7.25 -5.95 -10.25 -10.1 -9.55 Z" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.0"/>
      <path d="M8.95 6.45 L7.95 11.6 Q7.15 13.45 6.05 13.3 4.85 15.35 3.3 14.6 L0.25 15.1 -0.6 15.5 Q-1.4 15.9 -2.7 14.75 -3.95 15.15 -5.4 13.6 -6.55 13.75 -7.8 11.6 L-8.75 6.45 Q-7.05 5.55 -5.7 7.0 -3.9 6.1 -2.7 7.35 L3.4 7.3 Q4.75 6.25 6.15 6.95 7.7 5.75 8.95 6.45" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.0"/>
      <path d="M1.3 3.7 L0.8 0.3 M-1.3 3.7 L-0.75 0.3" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.5"/>
    </g>
  </defs>
</svg>


The free editor Inkscape  has an operation to decompose symbols/defs: "Edit/Clone/unlink clones recursively". You can then also ungroup all elements to get rid of transformations.

You are a hero, that worked!
